# Not going into while loop on another computer - MFC C++

Tags: c++, mfc

I have made a program whose function is to read a .log file that is being updated every milliseconds 24/7.

I am not going to go into much details on how the program works as that is going to be a long post so here is a summary of it:-

What my program does:-

1) Has a config file that user can change variable such as time_interval and such

2) User puts in 5 minutes(or however frequent they want it) and runs my program, my program will then scan the said text file when the 5 minutes is up and then scans again after another 5 minutes.

3) it checks for certain flags in the text file and records it if it changes values

4) it then prints it out into a .csv file

In the end, this is a program that is requested of me to ease database tracking for a machine that logs data on its components in a text file (pass/fail)

**Problem**

This program works flawlessly on the computer I made it in (Windows 7) and I tested it on another computer aswell running Windows 2000.

When i pass this program to the client who runs it on Windows XP it doesnt seem to go in the while loop that I have set it to go.

**My Code**

```
void CSerco_Parser_ToolDlg::Read_Log()
{
int result;
char ReadLogLine[100000] = "";
CString LogPathName;
FILE *readLOG_fp;
LogPathName = Source_Folder + "\\Test.log";

readLOG_fp = fopen(LogPathName, "a+t");

MessageBox("Before While Loop");
while ((result = fscanf(readLOG_fp, "%[^\n]\n", ReadLogLine)) != EOF) // Loops through the fil till it reaches the end of file
{
    CurrLine = ReadLogLine;

    if ((first_run) && (first_run_check))
    {
        MessageBox("first run true, first run check true");
        CurrLine_Final = CurrLine;
        Sort_Array();  // I have MessageBoxes in this to tell me that I have went into this function
        Comp_State();  // I have MessageBoxes in this to tell me that I have went into this function
    }
else
    {
        MessageBox("not hitting anything");
    }
}
fclose(readLOG_fp);

GenerateCSV();  // I have MessageBoxes in this aswell
```

}

**Sort Array function**

In this I basically sort the current line that I am reading from the .log file into its own array

**Comp State function**

In this I take the values that I have stored into the array in Sort Array and compare the the values inside and if it is different, I then store the differences into another array to print

**Generate CSV function**

As the name suggest, this is to print the differences into a .csv file.

**Final problem**

When i run it as per normal on my computer, it prints all the differences into a .csv file perfectly and shows all the messageboxes that I have set correctly.

but when the client runs it on his computer, it fails to go into this while loop

```
while ((result = fscanf(readLOG_fp, "%[^\n]\n", ReadLogLine)) != EOF)
```

and prints out

```
MessageBox("Before While loop");
```

and subsequently jumps to this function

```
GenerateCSV();
```

and since it didnt go through the while loop, there is nothing stored into the arrays to be printed out. Thus, resulting in the program not doing anything.

**Question**

Why is it doing this?

It shouldn't be OS specific as I tested it out on an older OS as compared to XP.

It is not the file being empty as I made sure about it. (double check, triple check...)

It is not the pathname to the .log file. (again double , triple check and so on)

It is not due to privileges (asked my client about it)

Only thing I can think of is that for some reason it goes into the .log file and straight jumps to the EOF. But why is it working perfectly when i test it on my own computer.

Comment: Have you checked the clients logfile, that it's correct and not empty?

Comment: basic questions: do you recompile on the XP machine? Do you have the Source_Folder on the XP machine?

Comment: Yeap, I have done that. I tried using a test.log file aswell with my own defined values so i could make sure it wasnt the clients logfile that is giving the problem.

Comment: And why, if you're only supposed to read the file, are you opening it in `"a+"` mode?

Comment: I have it as a+ as at the end of each day, I will be changing the file name and then creating a new file with the exact name. Example. at the end of the day Ill change the name serco.log to serco.log.[DATE] and then creating a new .log file called serco.log

Comment: You left out the single most important detail: What is `Source_Folder` and how do you retrieve it? It's also somewhat important to do error handling. You never check the return value of `fopen`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not going into the `while` loop when it must be because the call to `fscanf` is returning `EOF`.

Have you checked that the call:

```
readLOG_fp = fopen(LogPathName, "a+t");
```

Is actually returning a valid file pointer? If it is then check that the file isn't empty in the first place.

You might also want to check permissions. The log file may exist but your program may not have permission to open it.

Comment: Ok, understood that it is returninf EOF and thats why it is not going into the while loop. The file definitely is not empty. I suspected that my program may not have permission to open the file so i created my own test.log file with my own values inside and it works fine both on my computer, and some other computers that I have tested on running older OS. Any reason why it is not working on only the clients computer?